# If $|A|<|B|$ does $B$ surject onto $\aleph(A)$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

After reading [Proving existence of a surjection $2^{\aleph_0} \to \aleph_1$ without AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/407833/50776) I became curious if there is a generalization to arbitrary cardinals. That is, if $\frak m<n$, does it follow that $\frak m^+\le^*n$? Or in terms of sets:

> Suppose $A,B$ are sets, and there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ but not from $B$ to $A$ (so $|A|<|B|$). Does there exist a surjection from $B$ to $\aleph(A)$, where $\aleph(A)$ is the least ordinal that does not inject into $A$?

Of course all these questions are trivial under choice, where $\le^*$ coincides with $\le$ and $\frak m<n$ coincides with $\frak m^+\le n$ by trichotomy.

---

The proof methods given in the linked problem generalize in the following manner in the case $|B|\ge^*|{\cal P}(A\times A)|$ (for convenience I assume that $B={\cal P}(A\times A)$ but it is easy to compose with a surjection). For each $\alpha\in\aleph(A)$ we know that there is an injection from $\alpha$ to $A$, which induces a well-order of a subset of $A$. Thus for each $\alpha\in\aleph(A)$ there is an $R\in{\cal P}(A\times A)$ such that $R$ is a well-order of type $A$ (note that by using reflexive well-orders we can keep track of the domain of the well-order), so we can define our surjection ${\cal P}(A\times A)\to\aleph(A)$ by sending each well-order of type $\alpha$ to $\alpha$ and everything else to $0$.

In the language of cardinals, this means that ${\frak n}\le^* 2^{\frak m\times m}\to{\frak m}^+\le^*{\frak n}$, and if $\frak m\times m=m$ as is the case with alephs we get ${\frak m}^+\le^*2^{\frak m}$, which gives the original question for ${\frak m}=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Suppose that $A$ is a Dedekind-finite set such that $\aleph_0\nleq^*|A|$. For example if $A$ is an amorphous set. Then $B=A\cup\{A\}$ is such that $|A|<|B|$ and $\aleph_0\nleq^*|B|$.

(This example can be easily generalized. Given a $\kappa$-amorphous set $A$ such that $\aleph(A)=\kappa$, take $B=A\times\{0,1\}$. Then $|A|<|B|$, since $B$ can be split into two sets neither of which has size $<\kappa$, but if $B$ can be mapped onto $\kappa$, then $A$ could be mapped onto $\kappa$.

And the existence of an $A$ like that is consistent with $\sf DC_{<\kappa}$ for a regular cardinal $\kappa$.)